# regexp in switch statement

Tags: php, switch-statement

Are regex's allowed in PHP switch/case statements and how to use them ?

Comment: can you clarify this by giving an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Switch-case statement works like if-elseif.
As well as you can use regex for if-elseif, you can also use it in switch-case.

```
if (preg_match('/John.*/', $name)) {
    // do stuff for people whose name is John, Johnny, ...
}
```

can be coded as:

```
switch $name {
    case (preg_match('/John.*/', $name) ? true : false) :
        // do stuff for people whose name is John, Johnny, ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: This only works when `$name` evaluates to `true`. If `$name == ''` this will yield wrong results. -1

Comment: @nikic: you're right but this answers the OP's question : `Are regex's allowed in PHP switch/case statements and how to use them ?`

Comment: Took me a while to understand why this works. And I think it is an ugly hack. The key is that "most" strings validate to true. And the answer to the question would be: it works, most of the times.

Comment: switch $name { case (preg_match('/e*/', $name)): echo "match";break;} shouldn't work correctly for $name = "" because preg_match('/e*', $name) is true but true != "".

Comment: To save a few keystrokes, you can simply use:

`case 1 == preg_match('/john.*/', $name): `

Comment: If $name doesnt evaluate to true, a workaround would be `case (preg_match('/John.*/', $name) ? $name : !$name) :` to make sure you always match the switch on regex match, even if its a sign that you should be doing this in a different way.

Comment: Old thread but still, "case" is meant to evaluate a single value and execute what it's after, untill "break". Want more matches same code, use multiple "case" one after another. 
Don't try to use condition as "case" evaluation, "case" itself it's an evaluation, won't work as expected.

Comment: The `preg_match()` statement in `case` in the answer can be simplified as  
`case (!!preg_match('/John.*/', $name)):`

Answer (score 20):

No or only limited. You could for example switch for `true`:

```
switch (true) {
    case $a == 'A':
        break;
    case preg_match('~~', $a):
        break;
}
```

This basically gives you an `if`-`elseif`-`else` statement chain, but with syntax and might of `switch` (for example fall-through.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Then is it better (more readable) to do an if-elseif ?

Comment: @M42: If you don't want to fall-through (by not `break`ing) you should use `if`. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, but you should use this technique to avoid issues when the switch argument evals to `false`:

```
switch ($name) {
  case preg_match('/John.*/', $name) ? $name : !$name:
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If i understand well, i can do `preg_match("/regex/", $foo) ? true : false;`. Can't I ?

Comment: The first example in this answer is better than all the other answers because it will always correctly match (or not) the subject of the `switch()`, whereas returning true or false from the `preg_match()` ternary could have unexpected results, as in @NikiC's empty string example.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind the above answer can be slightly optimized like this:

Changing:

```
switch $name {
    case (preg_match('/John.*/', $name) ? true : false) :
        // do stuff for people whose name is John, Johnny, ...
        break;
}
```

To:

```
switch $name {
    case (bool)preg_match('/John.*/', $name) :
        // do stuff for people whose name is John, Johnny, ...
        break;
}
```