# PHP regular expression weird behavior

Tags: php, regex

I started having hands with regular expressions in PHP and stuck in start.

I have written following block:-

```
$object = "ng_amg_gt-1";

switch ($object)
{
    case preg_match('/^ng_amg_gt-[0-9]+$/', $object):
        echo 'first';    
        break;

    case preg_match('/^ng_amg_gt-_cg-[0-9]+$/', $object):
        echo 'second';
        break;

}
```

I thought "ng_amg_gt-1" will match preg_match('/^ng_amg_gt-[0-9]+$/', $object) but interestingly(anoyingly) it is echoing **second**.

What I am missing?

PS :- It may seem an obvious question but not getting any breakthrough, thats why I have posted it over here.

Thanks

Comment: preg_match returns an int, you're doing a switch on a string, and I dont even know if that's valid. Just do an `if (preg_match(...))`

Comment: oh NO, I did a blunder,  Apologies

Comment: Have look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4046018/372239

Answer (score 2):

> **What I am missing?**

Here is what you missed:

```
$object = "ng_amg_gt-1";

if(preg_match('/^ng_amg_gt-[0-9]+$/', $object)) {
    echo 'first';
} else if(preg_match('/^ng_amg_gt-_cg-[0-9]+$/', $object)) {
    echo 'second';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, I got an idea from this

Answer (score 1):

preg_match returns the number of pattern matches and you compare that to a string

Comment: I offer mea-culpa for this blunder