# How to display an array $key with this pattern promote-1 for which 1 can be any whole number?

Tags: php

```
function name( $key, $value ) {
    switch( $key ) {
        case 'name':
            break;
        // this is where I would determine the key with this pattern 1-100
        case 'promote-'.count++ : 
            break;
    }

}
```

When I echo the `$key` sample outputs would be `contact_number`, `card_name` and the pattern I would like to determine `promote-1`, `promote-2` and so on. The second option "case 'promote-'.count++" is the pattern I need to determine. That any 'promote-1' to 'promote-100' will fall on that option

Comment: `count` is not a legal variable, and you're not concatenating properly

Comment: possible duplicate of [regexp in switch statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043741/regexp-in-switch-statement)

Comment: Thanks @SterlingArcher, It's just an example on what would it looks like. When I echo the $key, there is this $key that I need to put in the switch with this value 'promote-1', 'promote-2' and so on. I need to detect this pattern for my switch case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use of switch case is very restricted. Here is a working solution for you.

```
function name( $key, $value ) {
    if(strpos($key,'-') > 0){
        $key_arry = explode('-' , $key);
        if($key_arry[0] == 'promote' && ($key_arry[1] > 0 || $key_arry[1] <= 100)){
            echo 'Patern is promote-1, promote-2......promote-100';
        }else{
            echo 'anything else';
        }
    }

}
name('promote-2' , 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `regex`

```
    case (preg_match('/promote-\d/', $key) ? true : false) :
       // do stuff for people whose name is John, Johnny, ...
       break;
```

`'/promote-\d/'`this will check for patterns - `promote-<any digit>`

Comment: Did you get this straight from the duplicate that I linked in the comment about an hour ago?

Comment: used that solution some days ago... anything wrong with it?