# Preg_match in switch case in PHP?

Tags: php, switch-statement, preg-match, case

I am making switch function in php and I wonder if is it possible to make one of the cases like that:

```
switch($message){
        case 'hi':
            $output = $jsonWelcome;
            break;
        case preg_match('/start/', $message):
            $output = $jsonHelp;
            break;
}
```

I want to execute that last case when $message would be for example: "project start" or "start project". I think that's because preg_match return 0 or 1. Is there any way to make this code works?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could always do an if statement

Comment: use `if/elseif/else` instead of a `switch`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
switch($message){
        case 'hi':
            $output = $jsonWelcome;
            break;
        case (preg_match('/start/', $message) ? true : false):
            $output = $jsonHelp;
            break;
}
```

Should work fine.

Example working code:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99ab518718ce9488277619a33dbfdf353f0c2316

Comment: You are adding a condition statement, into a case statement. This only make things more complicated and verbose.

Comment: @akDeveloper I somewhat agree. But, considering its within the specification of the question I believe its totally valid. I do think an if/else tree would be more appropriate but there is obviously a reason why the OP has disregarded that.

Comment: If you think that an if/else statement was more appropriate then your answer should include an if/else. Personally in this case i am more with `switch(true)` which acts as if/else but with better structure.

Comment: Also @iyop45, your code will not  work correctly in case of `$message = null` or `$message = ""`

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want to save your code more readable and compiler friendly:

```
switch($message){
        case 'hi':
            $output = $jsonWelcome;
            break;
        default:
            $output = preg_match('/start/', $message) ? $jsonHelp : "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this snippet:

```
switch(true){
        case $message == 'hi':
            $output = $jsonWelcome;
            break;
        case 1 == preg_match('/start/', $message):
            $output = $jsonHelp;
            break;
}
```

Where all conditions should evaluate `true`

Comment: What's the point of really even using a switch statement in this case?

Comment: `Switch` statements are more extensible than `if` statements and produce more clear code. So in future can add more conditions, without the need of restructure the code.

Comment: When you're using ```switch(true)``` you're making that point somewhat redundant. It's not standard usage and so in this case I think makes it less clear. For your code you'd need ```$message = "abc"``` for every single branch which renders the ```switch``` statement pointless.

Comment: That is correct. For this scenario an `if` `else` statement can make the job. But if someone wants to use a `switch` statement, i think that my example is more clear for this scenario. Imagine multiple `preg_match` cases. Then `$message` variable should appear in every branch too, right?

Comment: I've shorten my example, it has 9 conditions so far, and there is possible that there would be more in the future.

Comment: So @SebastianKopiczko you think that a `switch(true)` statement do the job?

Comment: @iyop45, following a link from Toto http://stackoverflow.com/a/4044025/395341 i see that NikiC suggests the same that Whiteulver does, for a similar problem. So i think that the answer of Whiteulver is more correct.

Comment: so, if it is not good practice, tell me how to solve problem when user put one word, for example: 'first' - do something, or put phrase, for example: 'start making dinner' - recognize word 'start' - do something because of this word and substring ' making dinner' and pass it to other variable?

Comment: @SebastianKopiczko what you describe, it fits the logic of a Routing system, in my opinion. I think that using a routing like system, will serve you better than an `if/else` or a `switch` statement. FastRoute https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute can be easy customized to fit your needs.