# Look for any characters in PHP switch cases

Tags: php, switch-statement, character, case, any

I need to have a case that checks for a few first characters, and then accept any other 7 characters. Something like this:

DN98???????

I tried doing it like this:

```
        case 'DN98'+'[a-zA-Z0-9]':
            $theme = 'correct-page';
            break;
```

but it only makes every url go to the "correct-page", not only those starting with DN98. I also tried:

```
        case 'DN98????????':
            $theme = 'correct-page';
            break;
```

But it doesn't do anything, just makes typing that code go to the default case, also tried the same but with "*", didn't work.

Anyone might help me out? I'm not that good with PHP.

Comment: That's not what `switch` does. You want `preg_match` in an `if..else`.

Comment: You could try with `preg_match()`: an answer here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043741/regexp-in-switch-statement)

Comment: Thank you guys, it worked, also is there an option to limit the amount of "any" characters to 7? It's not as important, but would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the first 7 characteres you can use the regex like this `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$` for the last 7.